# Invalid parameter while insert kernel module

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kernel-module

I wrote a simple kernel module and declared 3 parameters:

```c
#include<linux/module.h>

int date = 1, month = 1, year = 2000;
module_param(date, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(date, "date of time");
module_param(month, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(month, "month of time");
module_param(year, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(year, "year of time");

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Today is %d/%d/%d.\n", year, month, date);  // write to dmesg file
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this command:

```
sudo insmod hello.ko year=`date +%Y` month=`date +%m` date=`date +%d`
```

The terminal shows:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello.ko: Invalid parameters
```

So I check the dmesg log:

```
[ 4283.774215] hello: `09' invalid for parameter `date'
```

But when I chang the command to:

```
sudo insmod hello.ko year=`date +%Y` month=`date +%m` date=9
```

It worked!

```
[ 4373.679843] Today is 2023/7/9.
```

Why `date +%d` can't work but the others work?

Comment: Leading zero means an **octal** number, but octal digits are only 0-7. That is, `09` is invalid number, but `9` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your command on this way to avoid leading zeros in `date` command:

```
sudo insmod hello.ko year=`date +%Y` month=`date +%-m` date=`date +%-d`
```

(the `-` tell `date` not to add leading zero)